# I am working on localization TC and want to print in Japanese locale on Console

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, automation, localization

I want to print in Japanese locale on console so that I can run my project in Jenkins via maven command But it is always printing ?????(Refer screenshot).
I have written this -Dproject.build.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 and -Dproject.reporting.outputEncoding=UTF-8 in goals but still it is not printing.
I have tried with -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 also but didn't work.
I have added encoding in surefire plugin and also in compiler plugin on pom.xml but still no luck.
Can someone help me know where I'm getting wrong?[[Goals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sksma.jpg)Console Output][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGcyH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can print `UTF-8` character this way

```
String unicodeMessage = "\u7686\u3055\u3093\u3001\u3053\u3093\u306b\u3061\u306f";

PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
out.println(unicodeMessage);
```

**Update:**

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
out.println("Notification List Header Text is: " + PLClinicalNotificationsHelper.getNotificationsListHeaderText());
```

Comment: I have set my application locale to Japanese so that when i run my TC through command line it should print in Japanese. But it is printing????.

Comment: Actually it's is exact same text but you have to specify in output stream also for `UFT-8` so that  it write UTF-8 byte sequences to the underlying OutputStream

Comment: I don't want to specify in output stream. I have written assertion in my code. I want my code to change the locale to Japanese and then verify the assertion and print the actual value on console in Japanese language. Likewise if I change the locale to any other language then accordingly it should verify the assertion and should print the actual value on console in the same language. That's how I want it but instead of Japanese it is printing ?????.

Comment: Add the code in your post how you print in console.

Comment: I am printing like this   System.out.println("Notification List Header Text is: "
                + PLClinicalNotificationsHelper.getNotificationsListHeaderText());

Comment: I update how you should print `UFT-8` character, it's just about print. If data is properly coming it will print propertly

Comment: Is it okay now ?

Comment: It is printing on console and I may consider this solution. Is there any way to print on cmd prompt in Japanese. I am using this maven command to run on cmd   mvn clean install -Dca.server.host.name=INBLREVRACHA044.eng.med.ge.com -Dforce.certificate=true -Dmeta.filter=+BDD4327_localization -Dproject.build.sourceEncoding=UTF-8